# How can I append some radio buttons with loop and wrap it around a form element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I have an array and I want to append every element of this array as a radio button inside a specific DOM. My approach is to loop over the array.

However, I want to create an html `form` element that wraps around this newly with jQuery created radio buttons.

1. `form` opening tag.
2. Loop over the array and append all radio buttons.
3. `form` closing tag.

The form element is openend and closed immediately, then follows the radio buttons created by the loop.

I think its because of the async nature of JavaScript.

```js
let arr = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Tomatoe', 'Sugar'];

function loop_append(elem) {
  $('a').append(`
                <label for=${elem}>${elem}</label
                <input type="radio" name="${elem}"></input></br>`

      function radioButtonappender() {
        $('.a').append('<form name="test">');

        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          loop_apend(arr[i]);
        }

        $('.a').append('</form>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="A">
  <div class="a">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Expected result:**

```
<div class="A">
    <div class="a">

        <form name="test">
        /* -> ALL THE RADIO BUTTONS AND LABELS */
         </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Actual (wrong) result**

```
<div class="A">
    <div class="a">

        <form name="test"> </form>
        /* -> ALL THE RADIO BUTTONS AND LABELS */

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach (in vanilla javascript), using:

- a `for...of` loop
- `document.createElement()`
- `.setAttribute()`
- `.textContent`
- `.appendChild`

**Working Example:**

```js
let arr = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Tomato', 'Sugar'];

function addRadioButtonsForm(arr) {
  
  const a = document.getElementsByClassName('a')[0];
  
  // BUILD THE FORM
  let form = document.createElement('form');
  form.setAttribute('name', 'test');
  
  for (element of arr) {
    
    // BUILD THE LABEL
    let label = document.createElement('label');
    label.setAttribute('for', element);
    label.textContent = element;
    form.appendChild(label);
        
    // BUILD THE RADIO BUTTON
    let radio = document.createElement('input');
    radio.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
    radio.setAttribute('name', 'ingredients');
    form.appendChild(radio);
        
    // BUILD THE LINEBREAK
    let linebreak = document.createElement('br');
    form.appendChild(linebreak);
  }
  
  a.appendChild(form);
}

addRadioButtonsForm(arr);
```

```html
<div class="A">
  <div class="a">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: works, thanks. Since you seem to have appropriate knowledge about JS: Do you know how i force JS to execute a loop in between two statements?

Comment: @ArgentHo - Can you ask a new question with an example showing what you have tried and `@` me in the comments immediately below your question and I will see what I can do to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to vastly simplify things:

```
let arr = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Tomatoe', 'Sugar'];

$('.a').append('<form name="test"></form>');

for ( var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++ ) {
    $('form').append(`<label for=${arr[i]}>${arr[i]}</label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="${arr[i]}"></input></br>`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rounin's solution works, but for some reason the labels are not clickable, only the actual buttons.
I played around with it. I have not included the form element here:

```
function addRadioButtonsForm(array, myId) {
   const rbParent = document.getElementById('myId');
   for (let i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {
          // BUILD THE RADIO BUTTON
      let radio = document.createElement('input');
      radio.type = 'radio';
      radio.name = "options";
      radio.value = "option"+i ; 
      RBParent.appendChild(radio);
          // BUILD THE LABEL
      let label = document.createElement('label');
      label.textContent = options[i]+"\n";
      RBParent.appendChild(label);
          // BUILD THE LINEBREAK
      let linebreak = document.createElement('br');
      RBParent.appendChild(linebreak);
   };
}
```